# How to create an index to be picked by query

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

I have created multiple indexes one after another, but my query doesn't want to pick them :(

```
CREATE INDEX x 
  ON gan.paid (project_id, country_iso_code, source, date(created_at));
CREATE INDEX x 
  ON gan.paid (project_id, country_iso_code, text(source), date(created_at));
CREATE INDEX x 
  ON gan.paid (project_id, text(country_iso_code), text(source), date(created_at));
```

Query Plan:

```
WindowAgg  (cost=46024.07..52771.64 rows=24252 width=63) (actual time=3038.104..3072.217 rows=99983 loops=1)
 ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=46024.07..52468.49 rows=24252 width=63) (actual time=2284.136..2982.067 rows=99983 loops=1)
    Group Key: key
    ->  Sort  (cost=46024.07..46535.85 rows=204709 width=63) (actual time=2284.109..2805.815 rows=198575 loops=1)
          Sort Key: key
          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13960kB
          ->  Seq Scan on paid gap  (cost=0.00..20265.45 rows=204709 width=63) (actual time=0.024..215.813 rows=198575 loops=1)
                Filter: ((project_id = 1) AND ((country_iso_code)::text = 'gb'::text) AND ((source)::text = 'website'::text) AND (created_at <= (now())::date) AND (created_at >= ((now())::date - 100)))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 214895
Planning time: 0.233 ms
Execution time: 3082.612 ms
```

Query:

```
SELECT sum(views) vies
     , sum(likes) likes
     , key
     , count(*) OVER() full_count
FROM gan.paid
WHERE project_id = 1 
    AND country_iso_code = 'gb' 
    AND source = 'website' 
    AND created_at::date >= now()::date - 100 
    AND created_at::date <= now()::date
GROUP BY key;
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE gan.paid (
    id               integer pk
    key              text
    project_id       integer
    source           varchar
    country_iso_code varchar
    visits           integer
    likes            integer
    created_at       date
);
```

How can I create an index that will speed up this query?

Comment: How many rows does the query return (i.e. how many distinct `key` values are there in the table)? And please add the actual `CREATE TABLE` script, not just a list of columns. `key` column is missing by the way there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the part of the execution plan where you expect an index being used:

```
      ->  Seq Scan on paid gap  (cost=0.00..20265.45 rows=204709 width=63) (actual time=0.024..215.813 rows=198575 loops=1)
            Filter: ((project_id = 1) AND ((country_iso_code)::text = 'gb'::text) AND ((source)::text = 'website'::text) AND (created_at <= (now())::date) AND (created_at >= ((now())::date - 100)))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 214895
```

What we have to look at is the number of rows this node returns (`198575`) and the number it *does not* return (`Rows Removed by Filter: 214895`).  This means that the conditions in your `WHERE` clause are not really selective - they specify nearly half of the whole table.

This is a situation where indexes seldom help - they usually said to kick in when the percentage of the returned rows is estimated to be under 10% (others say less, like 5%).

You can try the same query with a more selective set of conditions (practically, setting a narrower date range).  In this case, an index may help - the first one you list above, for example.  Depending on the distribution of the data (the different values of `project_id`, `source`, and `country_iso_code`, and the proportion of all rows having the specific values), a different order of the columns might be preferable (for example, `created_at::date` as the first column).  If the other columns are not selective enough in any case (for example, all rows have a project ID of 1), it can happen that you need `created_at::date` only.

At the same time, your problem seems not to be the (lack of) indexes, but that the query is sorting too much data.  This node:

```
->  Sort  (cost=46024.07..46535.85 rows=204709 width=63) (actual time=2284.109..2805.815 rows=198575 loops=1)
      Sort Key: key
      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13960kB
```

shows that the `work_mem` setting is too low - the query needs at least 13960 kB more memory for this sort.  Do a

```
SET work_mem TO xMB;
```

where x is {your current setting} + 16 MB.  This will spare you about 2 seconds.

**Notes:**

- casting `varchar` to `text` does not help with your indexes.
- Is this query just a part of a bigger picture?  If it isn't, I'd think a bit more about what I am planning to do with the nearly 100k rows returned.  It might mean a (slight) re-desing of your logic.

Comment: thx, the problem was indeed the one described by you, the index was picked as soon as I decreased my date range